# Change the text text-transform of the data in the column? [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb, lowercase

The data contained in a column is stored in uppercase.
Is it possible to automatically update all of the data in this column `SYSLOCE2` with lowercase letters?

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     SYSLOCE2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       SAMPLE     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       PEOPLE     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       HELLO      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |       WORLD      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lower()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower). It will convert all upper case letters in a string to the lowercase equivalent.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET sysloce2 = lower(sysloce2);
```